# UIScrollView using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm unable to get my scrollview to "stick" to the content that is scrolled to. The content is layed out side-by-side (2 UIViews inside UISrollView) and I'm able to slide it over to see, but as soon as I let go it bounces back. My understanding is this is an auto-layout problem however I don't understand what constraints I need to add in order to get this to work. I feel like I've tried everything but it either doesn't work or I get the "ambiguous scrollable content" error.

[image]

[image: document outline]

Comment: This probably isn't an auto-layout issue.  It could very easily be an incorrect content size value for the scroll view.

Comment: I've also tried setting the content size but also no luck:

    `CGSize contentSize = self.scrollViewBio.frame.size;
    contentSize.width *= 2;
    self.scrollViewBio.contentSize = contentSize;`

Comment: Can you add screen shot of Attributes Inspector,what are the properties you have set and Size Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out this problem! There are a lot of posts asking this but none of those answers helped me so I figured I'd update this one in case it helps someone else.

The issue I was experiencing was that the content inside my Scrollview was wider than the actual scrollview (which is the whole point). However when I added the constraint in Xcode to pin the content to the right side of the scrollview, it automatically sets it up with a negative constraint to its parent.

[image]

That's not what I intended since the scrollview's content will get resized and I always want my content inside of it pinned to the edge. I simply had to set this constant to 0 and then everything worked!

[image]
[image]